# Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in WAMP?

Tags: php, string, strpos

I am getting weird error in WAMP but not on my hosting, and the error is:

```
Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\corpo-child\functions.php on line 292
```

Function is:

```
function url( $atts, $content = null ) {
$cnt = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, '/', strpos($content, '/')+2));
$cnt = str_replace('http://www.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('http://', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('www.', '', $cnt);
$cnt = str_replace('embed.', '', $cnt);
    return '<div id="url"><a href="/external/?link='.$content.'" target="_blank">'.$cnt.'</a></div>';
}
```

Line 292 is:

```
$cnt = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, '/', strpos($content, '/')+2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a warning. I guess you have warnings enabled in WAMP, you can disable them using the [error_reporting();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) method:

```
// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Note: Calling this method once will set this option forever in PHP, so if you'd like to show warnings again, you have to use the same method with different arguments at a later time.

Now about the issue itself:

I think it's a problem with the offset argument you are using in:

```
$cnt = substr($content, 0, [OFFSET]);
```

This `[OFFSET]` value from the following method:

> strpos($content, '/', strpos($content, '/')+2)

Is probably larger than the context string itself. You can debug this very easily by printing the offset value and the context string on the page.

If this doesn't solve the problem, maybe this error is returned because a character isn't found in the string when using strpos. You should try breaking up the methods you use in more lines so you can trouble shoot the problem based on the line number that the warning returns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have this in wamp: error_reporting = E_ALL, what should I do to disable warnings? With error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE, I still have a warning.

Comment: You should give `E_ERROR | E_PARSE` a try, as argument. Indeed `E_ALL` shows all the warnings. I recommend you to enable this on your local computer, it's very useful to see the warnings so you can fix it, some warnings might result in an error later on. Check the code examples on the error_reporting(); page of PHP.Net for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Tried E_ERROR | E_PARSE, restarted all services, still Warning is on.

Comment: I guess I was wrong, sorry about that. There's a nice example here: http://d.pr/i/Cq3R. Give `E_ERROR` a try. Oh and you shouldn't have to restart all services :), the changes should apply instantly.

Comment: Works if I "display_errors = off", hmm, this will disable all errors and not only warnings not good solution, but works...

Comment: error_reporting = E_ERROR will still show this warning, so is this warning actually error, I don't know. But neither way with "error reporting = ???" disabled this notice. Only one I mentioned above.

Comment: If this still shows errors, it's probably the `display_errors` setting, change this to `Off` using `ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');` This should still show all errors (unless disabled with `error_reporting(...);`).